# How to determine if a USB power supply is safe to use with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: power-supply, failure, voltage

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that appears to have been destroyed this morning. I purchased a no-brand USB mains charger suitable for UK use (and CE certified) from eBay, and I am almost certain that was the culprit. It claims to produce up to 3.1A at 5V. It wasn't the cheapest available, either - I purchased it because it looked of reasonable quality!

It seemed to be working OK initially (green and red lights came on) but the HDMI output did not seem to be producing anything. I decided to unplug it and try a different charger, USB cable, HDMI TV socket, and I got one last gasp out of it (a green light) and then nothing since.

Now, if I plug the device into an old charger that used to power the Pi fine, the chips get extraordinarily hot (like, fire-risk hot), so I think it is sadly beyond repair. The central CPU chip gets to a temperature that easily burns fingertip skin. I have tried waiting for it to cool completely and then try again, to no avail.

I have (bravely and foolishly) tried the suspicious charger in a mifi device, and it seems to charge it OK. So, my question is whether there is a way I can test my charger device to see if it is producing electrical output within USB-defined standards? Are RPis known to be sensitive in this regard?

I guessed there was such a thing as a "USB voltage tester", and lo-and-behold, [there is](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/292076965244). Would that help?

I expect I would be looking for **over-voltage**, and not under-voltage. Whilst my understanding of electronic physics is fairly lacking, I guess I am not looking for an over-amperage, since devices take as much as they need?

(In the meantime I have learned my lesson: I'll only use official Raspberry Pi supplies in the future).

Comment: Buy the official 5.1V 2.5A 18Awg cable psu : https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/power-1051/power-supplies-1088/raspberry-pi-official-uk-and-eu-power-supply-5.1v-2.5a-black

Comment: @CoderMike: yep, will do. Any thoughts on how I can check the suspicious charger? If I can show it is producing voltage outside of expected parameters, I can contact the UK Trading Standards body and try to get it taken off sale. (It is very unlikely I can pass the costs of the burnt Pi onto the eBay trader, especially since they can't know if I did something else to cause the failure).

Comment: If the power supply has a usb socket you could measure the voltage on the usb pins. As your Pi appears to be dead you could try measuring the voltage on the +5V and GND GPIO pins with the problem psu plugged in.

Comment: @CoderMike: ah, thanks. I have a multimeter, so I can test this. [That would be here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/README.md), right?

Comment: Yes, e.g. pin2 5V, pin6 Gnd https://pinout.xyz

Comment: Marvellous, that's a nice website. Well, I have ordered my new Pi, and will be more careful with what I power it with, @CoderMike. Is it generally well known that they are this sensitive? I have been a Pi owner for some 18 months, and the (branded) phone charger I have previously been using was not a product of careful selection. Have I just been unlucky?

Comment: I've not known the Pi's to be sensitive - i've got about 20 Pi's ranging from the very first model - all still functioning. I've always bought power supplies from Raspberry Pi suppliers and always used the official psu's on my 3xPi3s. I've also played about with branded USB 2.4A power banks without issue.

Comment: Hmm, OK thanks @CoderMike. I did also plug it into a power supply that was insufficient (probably 1A output), and I did plug/unplug the HDMI whilst it was on. I would expect neither of those to be a problem. It's a ~£30 loss I can weather, but I'm sad at adding to landfill pointlessly, and I want to try to stop this from happening to other folks.